# Fixed point Iteration: Convergence & Divergence from geometrical figure

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I want to understand the geometrical interpretation of Convergence & Divergence of Fixed point iteration method.

The figure is here [IMAGE: CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJGiN.png)

In **Figure 2.4(a) Left panel**: if we draw a tangent at the point of intersection for the curve $g(x)$, the angle, say $\theta_1$, made between tangent and x-axis is less $45^o$, so slope $<tan(45)=1$. Therefore, $g'(P)<1$

In **Figure 2.5(a) Right panel**: if we draw a tangent at the point of intersection for the curve $g(x)$, the angle, say $\theta_2$, made between tangent and x-axis is greater than $45^o$, so slope $>tan(45)=1$. Therefore, $g'(P)>1$

If I am correct to understand the above two, then please help me to understand the below two.

> In **Figure 2.4(b) Left panel**: if we draw a tangent at the point of intersection for the curve $g(x)$, the angle, say $\theta_3$, made between tangent and x-axis is greater than $90^o$, so slope $\tan(\theta_3)=tan(90+\phi)=-cot \phi$, $0<\phi<90^o$. But this does not imply $ cot \phi<1$ for $0<\phi<90^o$ So $\tan(\theta_3)>-1$ is not true always.   **Then, how to get $-1<g'(P)<0$?**
>
> Also In **Figure 2.5(b) Right panel: How to get the $g'(P)<-1$?**

Edit: Angles $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$ are shown.
[image]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Figure 2.4(b) you have $\theta_3>135°$, so that $-1<\tan\theta_3<0$.
In Figure 2.5(b) you have $90°<\theta_4<135°$, so that $\tan\theta_4<-1$.

Comment: I have uploaded the fig with angles. If you are right, then if we move g(x) little up in fig 2.4 b, so that $\theta_3$  becomes just <135, then is convergence scenario replaced by divergence scenario? If it is true, then please help me to understand.

Comment: A similar thing happens with Figures 2.4(a) and 2.5(a). Is that case clear to you? If so, what is the difference with Figures 2.4(b) and 2.5(b)?

Comment: I am confused and not able to grasp the thing. Would you please help me to understand in a nutshell? Please.

Comment: Consider Figure 2.4(a) and let $(\bar x, \bar x)$ be the point where the two lines intersect. If $|g'(x)|<1$, then $|g(p)-\bar x|<|p-\bar x|$. On the other hand, $g(p_n)=p_{n+1}$, so previous inequality is the same as $|p_{n+1}-\bar x|<|p_n-\bar x|$, and sequence $p_n$ converges.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant Figure 2.4(b), of course, even if the reasoning is exactly the same as for the case of Figure 2.4(a).